# Stuck installing gisgraphy: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException

Tags: windows-7, gisgraphy

I'm been trying to get [gisgraphy](http://gisgraphy.com) to run for a few hours but seem to get stuck at the exception being thrown below.

I thought it might have been the  gisgraphy-3.0-beta2 version of gisgraphy but I now get the same with gisgraphy-2.1.1-final.

I've followed the instructions pretty closely.

I'm running on Windows 7 and Java version 1.8.

Googling has lead nowhere -- I wonder if I have a configuration mismatch.

```
C:\Users\bob\apps\gisgraphy>java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xmx1024m -Xms512m -jar start.jar 
ERROR [main] ContextLoader | Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from URL [file:/C:/Users/bob/apps/gisgraphy/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource is only available on Java 1.5 and higher
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:385)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:313)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:142)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:92)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:97)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:411)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:338)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:530)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:135)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:500)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:147)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:161)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:147)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:117)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:210)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
    at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:929)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:183)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:497)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:115)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource is only available on Java 1.5 and higher
    at org.springframework.transaction.config.TxNamespaceUtils.getAnnotationTransactionAttributeSourceClass(TxNamespaceUtils.java:43)
    at org.springframework.transaction.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser$AopAutoProxyConfigurer.configureAutoProxyCreator(AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java:117)
    at org.springframework.transaction.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java:79)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:69)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1246)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1236)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:133)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:468)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:363)
    ... 34 more
```

Comment: Welcome to gis.se. It would probably help if you can tell us which of "the instructions" you are following, and what commands you are using when the error occurs. Also, can you tell us what other services are running on this machine?

Answer (score 2):

It is due to a bug with java 8 and spring2.5 that is not compatible

It has been fixed in v 4.0 (update spring to version 3.0)